# How should I connect a new light to this wiring?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, ceiling, old-house

I am putting a new ceiling light on. What wire goes where? The light turns on when all red are in the middle one black in live a one black in neutral and the Earth I leave out. If I leave the Earth out will it cause any problem?

Old
[image: old light]

New
[image: new light]

That’s the instruction for the new light

[image]

That’s how I have connected the wires

[image]

Comment: Is this old style UK/Europe wiring?  What wiring is at the switch?

Comment: Is uk the old style, am trying to upload the old picture but won’t let me.. there was one black wire in the natural one black in the line and 2 reds in loop and the other wire with no colour was Earth

Comment: The new light just has natural live an earth x

Comment: Am not messing with the wires a before I do I turn the main fuse off. I thought the 2 red wear extra wire as in the old light it was in the LOOP. But with the new light there in no loop it’s just N, L AND the one with the sign witch I know is earth

Comment: That connector has been mis-used. For the two reds, one is live and the other is supply to the switch. The black with the red going to the switch is the switched supply to the lamp. The other black is the neutral.

Answer (score 4):

I hope you are still alive and reading this.  **You have just connected the live wires to the metalwork on your new light fitting!  Turn it off now.**

The bare copper wires are earths.  Connect both to the yellow and green stripy wire.  Connect the two reds to a small terminal block or Wago block.  One of the blacks should go to brown and one to blue.  It's impossible to tell from the photo which is which.